# How to display EntityProperty objects with their CanonicalName?

Tags: front-end, curated-data, display, entity

Is there a way to display `EntityProperty` objects with their `CanonicalName` instead of the text they are currently displayed with.  Some of the display texts bears no resemblance to the canonical name.  For example,

```
EntityProperty["Source", "Title"]
CanonicalName[%]
```

[image]

I would prefer to see `Title` or perhaps `Source | Title` for the object display instead of `source name` in the above example.  Also, where is the object display text (e.g. `source name`) stored?  Is it accessible?

Comment: `EntityProperty["Source", "Title"][[1]]`

Comment: @DavidG.Stork That is just pulling the first parameter out of `EntityProperty`. That is not what I am looking for.

Comment: I found part of the answer. The display text can be gotten from `CommonName`. For example, `CommonName@EntityProperty["Source", "Title"]`. Still looking on how to display the object with its `CanonicalName`.

Comment: Would you be ok with solutions that involve `Unprotect`, or are you looking for built in ways to do this?

Comment: @ChipHurst  I prefer built in. However, `Unprotect` solutions are still very informative.  If you have one please share it.